# How to prevent a portable OS from booting via a USB C port on my Surface Go 2

Tags: windows-10, security, microsoft-surface, usb-c

I have a new Surface Go 2 with a USB C port. I'd like to disable this port as a security measure, thereby preventing someone from using it to boot a portable OS and bypass my other security.

When I go to the Device Manager and right click on the 'USB Root Hub (USB 3.0)', there is no 'Disable Device' option. I have an older laptop that I've used these same steps to disable its USB drives *(albeit they are USB A and not C)*, but that doesn't seem to be available on the Go 2.

**How can I prevent a portable OS from booting via a USB C port on my Surface Go 2?**

Comment: If you have Secure Boot enabled (you should) then that will stop someone starting the Surface with a portable OS.

Comment: I had no idea that was a thing! That's far simpler than having to toggle a USB port!! TY!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern computers (and including your Surface) have a BIOS (UEFI) setting called Secure Boot.

Make sure Secure Boot is set to Enabled (ON).

That prevents starting with a portable operating system.

This was done by manufacturers (and Microsoft) to stop this practice of starting with another OS on a portable USB key.